# What is the benefit using route:cache in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, and also new to PHP.

I have the following command that Laravel 5 can cache the route:

```
$ php artisan route:cache
  Route cache cleared!
  Routes cached successfully!
```

**My Questions are:**

1. What is the Benefit using route:cache in Laravel 5?
2. Do I have to use it in production mode?
3. And what is the different between using route:cache and not using it? is it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does it do and what is the benefit?**

It's faster because the routes get precompiled, so Laravel loads from the compiled file instead of checking the routes file every time a request is made.

**Do I have to use it in production mode?**

No, of course not. It's a pretty small boost anyway, but it might be useful to some. I run it on larger sites with lots of users, but I tend to ignore the route cache if I build something small for myself.